# A div with relative position over a div float

Tags: css, html, position, css-float

I don't understand why a div with float right or left is not above a div with relative position or defined with a background color when the last one is declared after.

Here is the html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        Main container <br/><br/>

        <div class="header">This is the header</div>
        <div class="text-right">Right text</div>
        <div class="footer">This is the footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the css:

```
.header {
    background-color:blue;
    border: solid;
    color: white;
    border-color:black;
    height: 100px;
}

.text-right{
    float: right;   
    border: solid;
    background-color: green;
}

.container{
    padding: 10px;  
    border: solid;
}

.footer{
    padding-top: 50px;
    border: solid;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
```

I know that I can use a .clear: both rule to correct this problem but my main point is: why when I set the background-color or the position or both in the .footer rule, the float div is under the footer?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is a minimalistic JSFiddle example that shows the same problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/5Kefa/5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While reading this very good [post](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/understanding-css-positioning-part-1/), at the end of the post, the author talks about the z-order internal working but also say that if you want to learn more, [this next one will be a much more detailed article](http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/)

The key point is that the order in the z-axis where are put the elements.

Here is what the author says:

> If we do not specify any z-index values, the default stacking order
>   from closest to the user to furthest back is as follows:
>
> ```
> 1. Positioned elements, in order of appearance in source code
> 2. Inline elements
> 3. Non-positioned floating elements, in order of appearance in source code
> 4. All non-positioned, non-floating, block elements in order of source code
> 5. Root element backgrounds and borders
> ```

As we can see, the positioned elements(1) are always on top of non-positioned elements(3-4). If I put a `div` with just a `float` property, this element will not be "positioned" onto the surface.

In this case, the second element, my footer `div`, that is positioned with a relative property value will be at the top of the previous one not just I don't add a `clear: both` property after the `float` `div` property or because the last one is added after the floating element but because it is positioned!

Like powerbuoy said, you must set add a position relative to the float element to be able to go top of the stack the floating element. But it's not enough. Because these two elements are now at the same level and because they are both crossing each other, you must tell the engine which one will be the first and this is why you must set the z-order to 1 to the floating element again like said powerbuoy.

I'm not a very good writer and for this reason, I strongly suggest you to read the referenced articles that I mentioned previously. I think you will have a very deep explanation of the case.

Comment: Sorry to accept my own question but I think this is the correct answer and nobody have say the opposite.

Comment: Considering http://jsfiddle.net/wxMhx/. Hmm, if you add `position:relative;` to the `id=text-right`, then the `id=footer` still appears above the `text-right`.  Although the floating elem now has `position: relative`, so both the floating elem and the `id=footer` are positioned. So rule 1 should apply? -- **However** the floating elem appears **first** in the source, and so ought to be stacked **above** the `id=footer` (according to rule 1) in your example, right? Why then is the `id=text-right` nevertheless hidden by the `footer`, weird. (This with the z-index rule removed) (Google Chrome 19)

Comment: Perhaps there should be another entry in the 1,2,3,4,5 list that specifies where floating *and* positoned element should be placed. It seems to me that rule 1 does actually not apply to them.

Comment: I think the author of the blog post (http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/) might have done a mistake, or at least s/he is being unclear.  If you read the W3C spec, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html, you'll notice that what corresponds to rule 1 actually is: "*All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0', in tree order.*" But this is the order in which stuff should be *drawn*, that is, things that appear later in the source, should be painted *above* things that appear earlier -- and, in the source, `text-right` is before the `footer`.

Comment: If, however, you read rule 1 as is ("*Positioned elements, in order of appearance in source code*") it gives me the impression that things that appear first in the source, should be stacked above things that appear later. But according to the W3C spec it should be the other way around, that things that appear later in the source, are painted above their earlier siblings.

Comment: Another problem with the list?: The blog post author has reverse it, somewhat. Details: You should not read and match rules in order 1,2,3,4,5. The WC3 lists the rules the other way around, that is, first you attempt to match *root elem backgrounds*, then *all non-positioned elems* and so on. For example, consider an inline *and* positioned elem. The way the list is written in the blog post, rule **1** will match that positioned inline elem. But it should not. Instead, when you match rule 5 first then 4,3,2 -- you'll notice that rule **2** matches. And you'd stop there, and never test rule 1.

Comment: (Well now when you've read all this, perhaps it's a good idea to read the W3C spec as well:  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html  )

Comment: Hum.... I think you have dig more deeper than in me about the subject. I will read links that you posted and I wish we will found the absolute truth in the weird world of positionning div element. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Since the footer comes *after* the text-right it will be rendered on top of text-right. To avoid this you can give text-right a z-index (and a position other than static):

http://jsfiddle.net/wxMhx/

Edit: hmmm... no that's not entirely correct. If you remove position: relative; from the footer text-right will be rendered on top of it. TBH I'm not sure *why* that happens. But the solution in either case is to either remove position: relative; from the footer, or add it (as well as a z-index) to text-right.

Comment: Thank you for your time... I read a lot on the web and found this sentence: "So the behavior is intended to be to first float it, and influence other elements in that spot and only then move it to a new shifted position without influencing the position of other elements again. ". With what you said, what I understand is that when you place a div float followed by another div with relative position, the last one will hide the previous if a background-color is set. It is a common situation or do I messed something?

Comment: Even without a background image text-right is behind the footer but it's still visible because there's nothing rendered om top of it. Position: relative i think is what triggers the layering. I'm afraid I don't know why though. But I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

Because `position: relative`. If you delete this line you will see `div` with `text-right` class. You can set `z-index: -1;` to `footer` class and this should work as well.

Comment: Thank you but like I said in my question, I want to know why this happen, not how to correct the problem.